# Slow application after some time

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

My application uses WCF to get data from the central server and place on a local server. I have to fetch 93000 records, and caught 250 records per request. The first requests go reasonably fast, 18-20 records per second. After a time, around 10-15 minutes, perfomece begins to fall gradually and reaches 5-6 records per second.

I do not use any framework. I am using NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2012 with data compatibildiade with 2005.

Have you tried to find the problem and I see nothing wrong with the source.
Is there any apparent reason for the gradual slow?

### Edit

Not error in .Net C#

I have an application that grabs data from a WebService and saved in a SQL Server 2012 database with empty tables, the perfomece is 20 records per second. After the insert of 7500-10000 records peforme begins to fall gradually after reaching 20,000 records in tables, drops to 5 records per second.

**I delete all the keys and triggers**

Comment: How does it page the data to only get 250 records?

Comment: Increased size of data?  Memory leak?  Performance bottleneck?  There's no *apparent* reason to us because you haven't shown us anything about the code which does this...

Comment: @Steve edit post e add code

Comment: Do you actually have a `while (true)` in your code?

Comment: This code is a legacy code, that the old programmer used to record while you have to be picked up from the server, continue to do the process. 'm Giving maintenance. I also find it very strange ...

Comment: You might get better help if you translate this code to English.

Comment: @Dalorzo there's also a break to get out when the job's done. Looks legit.

Comment: `Helper` seems important...what is it?

Comment: It's not obvious, and as others have said, you'll have to profile the code to see what's wrong. One hint: whenever I hear "performance of my long-running code gets worse over time", I think "not disposing all instances implementing `IDisposible`". I see some `using` blocks, but maybe there's something else that's escaping.

Comment: What is your clustered index on this table? If it is a quid (uniqueidentifier) you will hit around 99% index fragmentation at around 9-10k rows. It will not get any better unless you defragment the index. Could this be part of the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to profile your application to see where it is slowing down. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) is a walk-thru for using Visual Studio 2013 to profile.

Performance Counter data can be very useful as well. It can tell you if the processor use is spiking, disk queue is backing up, network traffic is increasing, or memory is maxing out.

When working with many thousands of new objects you may experience slowness within [Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc(v=vs.110).aspx)  as the heap grows. This is really a symptom of your application design, but it may point you to the right place in the code.

Comment: I don't really see how GC would be an issue. After a while, the rate of GC should become steady. Why would it get worse over time?

Comment: My thought was that once they reached the steady 5-6 records per second, that implied something (GC?) had reached an equilibrium.

Comment: But once it reaches an equilibrium, the performance shouldn't keep getting worse.

Comment: The post says that it starts out at 18-20 records per second, and then eventually drops to 5-6. It doesn't say if it gets worse than that?

Comment: Ah, good point. I missed that. 5-6 may _be_ the equilibrium point.

Comment: With your help, one click "idea" to take the test in this way came. Starts the import of data, which was checked with 20 records per second, I was monitoring, and after 5 minutes it was to record for 16 seconds. I went into the database and deleted the records of the tables involved, and returned to 20 records per second, and then begins to get worse again. Never drops of 6 records per second in the worst situation. With this I am checking the database to see what's wrong. tks

Comment: Interesting... maybe an insert trigger or large index is causing the problem?

Comment: @mpeterson I delete all the keys and triggers and slow continue